# Nested structs and pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct, nested

I have spent ages trying to figure out what is the problem with the following program:

```
typedef struct user {
    char host[40];
    int order;
} user;

typedef struct data {
    user userdat;
} data;

int read_user (char *datname, user *userdat) {
    ...

    fscanf (datin, "%s", &userdat->host);
    fscanf (datin, "%d", &userdat->order);

    //1
    printf ("%d\n", userdat->order);

    ...

}

void init_data (data *dat) {
    init_userdat (&dat->userdat);
}

void init_userdat (user *userdat) {
    *userdat->host = "127.0.0.1";
    userdat->order = 0;
}

int user_print (int i, data *dat) {
    //2
    printf ("%d\n", dat->userdat.order);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    ...
    data dat;
    init_data (&dat);
    read_user (datname, &dat->userdat);
    user_print (&dat);
}
```

The program is very simplified to highlight the relevant sections. What happens is that the first print statement (//1) outputs the value correctly, while the second (//2) does not - it outputs something that looks like a possible memory location.

I have tried numerous combinations of accessing the stored variable, but I just can't crack it. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit1: Fixed up a couple of non essential errors in code (not relating to pointers or structs)

**Final Edit: Thank you all for your help. The issue that Arun Saha pointed out was indeed in the original code and is now fixed. However, the problem of printing two different strings persisted. Your assurance that the code should otherwise compile and work led me to discover the true culprit - I was not properly initializing another part of the otherwise complex struct and this resulted in overwriting of the user.order variable.**

Comment: What is `datname` in main?

Comment: Not to mention `init_user()`.

Comment: Thank you for trying to simplify your code to illustrate your issue. It is very important that when you do so, you compile the code to make sure you do not introduce additional errors, though. Please compile and clean up any compiler errors so that we can help you fix the real issue.

Comment: Sorry about that, init_user should be init_userdat, datname is the name of the file. I edited the code now.

Comment: Check that your `fscanf()` calls succeed. And please make sure your code compiles (use `/* ... */` or `// ...` to indicate missing code, for example). Please learn about how to create an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).  And please make sure your code compiles cleanly before you submit it — or make your question about "How do I fix this compilation warning". Remember, your compiler knows a lot more about C than you do at the moment. Trust it; it is more likely to be right than you are. (Believe me, I trust the compiler to tell me when I've been silly too!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following line does not do what it appears to do :-)

```
*userdat->host = "127.0.0.1";
```

`userdata->host` is a pointer to the first character in the `host[40]` array. The above statement would copy only one character from the source string ("127.0.0.1"). To copy the entire string, use the standard library function `stncpy()`

```
strncpy( & userdata->host[ 0 ], "127.0.0.1", 40 );
```

Comment: You're right; that code doesn't do what is expected.  Worse than that, though, it should be generating compilation warnings (about assigning a pointer to a `char` or thereabouts).  Please (@user2253444) make sure your code compiles cleanly before submitting, or ask specifically for help fixing a specific warning.

Answer (score 1):

In your `main` function, when you invoke `read_user (datname, &dat->userdat);`, I feel there should be a compilation issue. This should be actually `read_user (datname, &dat.userdat);` as `dat` is not a pointer, but an object itself.

With this change and Arun's previous recommendation, I have tried your program and it works.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. The error was introduced while I was simplifying the code for presentation here.